# Why can't acces to instagram recent media?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am working with instagram api, to get top media and recent media, i don't have problems calling top media, but 2 days ago i implemented this and called 3 last recent media to my page,
today like 1 hour ago i only could see 1 of three last media i called and now after 1 hour can't see any of them when i print the array who contains recent media it says its empty i don't know why.
Checking calls from my application graphic it doesn't show a big traffic, so i think it's not the problem because i can see top media.

```
<?php
include 'define.php';

function makeApiCall($endpoint, $type, $params)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    if ('POST' == $type) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    } elseif ('GET' == $type) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response, true);
}

$hashtag = 'sedapal';
$hashtagId = '17843308429009249';


$hashtagSearchEndpoingFormat = ENDPOINT_BASE . 'ig_hashtag_search?user_id={user-id}&q={hashtag-name}&fields=id,name';
$hashtagDataEndpointFormat = ENDPOINT_BASE . '{hashtag-id}?fields=id,name';
$hashtagTopMediaEndpointFormat = ENDPOINT_BASE . '{ig-hashtag-id}/top_media?user_id={user-id}&fields=id,caption,children,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink';
$hashtagRecentEndpointFormat = ENDPOINT_BASE . '{ig-hashtag-id}/recent_media?user_id={user-id}&fields=id,caption,children,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink';


$hashtagSearchEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . 'ig_hashtag_search';
$hashtagSearchParams = array(
    'user_id' => $instagramAccountId,
    'fields' => 'id,name',
    'q' => $hashtag,
    'access_token' => $accessToken
);
$hashtagSearch = makeApiCall($hashtagSearchEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagSearchParams);

/* To get hashtagID */
/* echo '<pre>';
print_r($hashtagSearch);
die(); */


$hashtagDataEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $hashtagId;
$hashtagDataParams = array(
    'fields' => 'id,name',
    'access_token' => $accessToken
);
$hashtagData = makeApiCall($hashtagDataEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagDataParams);


$hashtagTopMediaEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $hashtagId . '/top_media';
$hashtagTopMediaParams = array(
    'user_id' => $instagramAccountId,
    'fields' => 'id,caption,children,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink',
    'access_token' => $accessToken
);
$hashtagTopMedia = makeApiCall($hashtagTopMediaEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagTopMediaParams);
$topPost = $hashtagTopMedia['data'][0];
$topPost1 = $hashtagTopMedia['data'][1];

$hashtagRecentEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $hashtagId . '/recent_media';
$hashtagRecentParams = array(
    'user_id' => $instagramAccountId,
    'fields' => 'id,caption,children,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink',
    'access_token' => $accessToken
);
$hashtagRecent = makeApiCall($hashtagRecentEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagRecentParams);
$recentPost = $hashtagRecent['data'][0];
/* $recentPost2 = $hashtagRecent['data'][1];
$recentPost3 = $hashtagRecent['data'][2]; */
?>
<p><?php echo json_encode($hashtagRecent['data']) ?></p>
```

[image: insta error]

[image: application graphic]

Comment: I think instagram changed some api's. Also problem with instagram_oembed endpoin, when getting post, expiration date of them only 6 hours, before was 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `recent_media` "Only returns media objects published within 24 hours of query execution", as said in [the `recent_media` documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag/recent-media/).

The posts you couldn't see anymore were probably older than 24 hours the second time you fetched them.

`top_posts` will return posts no matter how old they are.

I struggled with this too and that was what happened to me.